# Formatting a name from first, middle-initial and last

Tags: cobol

Record has name in this format:

```
01 LAST-NAME    PIC X(18).

01 FIRST-NAME   PIC X(12).

01 MI-NAME      PIC X(01).
```

The last and first names can of course be any size when they come in.

I need to put the name fields together (with no trailing spaces - but with a SPACE between each name) into a single working storage field 42 spaces in length:

```
01 WS-FULL-NAME PIC X(42)
```

Example:

```
LAST-NAME = Smithington 

FIRST-NAME = Edward

MI-NAME = H
```

Desired result:

```
Edward H Smithington
```

If Middle initial is blank I of course don't include it and desired result would be:

```
Edward Smithington
```

I have a routine to determine the actual length of each name field already that takes care of the trailing spaces (*I don't need to worry about leading spaces) (SEE BELOW):

```
      01 W-SUB   PIC 9(02) VALUE 0.

      PROCESS-LAST-NAME.

          PERFORM VARYING W-SUB FROM LENGTH OF LAST-NAME BY -1
            UNTIL W-SUB LESS THAN 1   
            OR LAST-NAME(W-SUB:1) NOT = ' '
          END-PERFORM 

       IF W-SUB > ZERO          
          MOVE LAST-NAME(1:W-SUB) TO  ?????
```

'MOVE LAST-NAME(1:W-SUB) TO  ?????' is where I am 'stuck'.

i.e. How to 'STRING' the three name fields together to produce DESIRED RESULT = Edward H Smithington (* Including a space between F, MI + L).

Answer (score 3):

You were asked to do it with `STRING`. The argument against using STRING for names is that names can have embedded spaces. `DE LA HAYE` for instance as a last-name, 'ST JOHN' (pronounced sinjun) as a first-name. There can also be typos giving leading blanks and embedded blanks. You seem to know that you have no leading blanks, but genuine or false embedded blanks make the simple use of STRING more tricky.

If you can guarantee no leading or embedded blanks (absolutely guarantee) then

```
IF MI-NAME EQUAL TO SPACE
    STRING                      FIRST-NAME 
                                 DELIMITED BY SPACE
                                ' '
                                 DELIMITED BY SIZE
                                LAST-NAME
                                 DELIMITED BY SPACE
       INTO                     FULL-NAME
ELSE
    STRING                      FIRST-NAME 
                                 DELIMITED BY SPACE
                                ' '
                                 DELIMITED BY SIZE
                                MI-NAME
                                 DELIMITED BY SIZE
                                ' '
                                 DELIMITED BY SIZE
                                LAST-NAME
                                 DELIMITED BY SPACE
       INTO                     FULL-NAME
END-IF
```

Before the IF you need to MOVE SPACE to FULL-NAME, else you'll end up with part of the previous name when the current name is shorter than the previous.

If you can't guarantee the lack of leading and embedded blanks, you have to use reference-modified fields for the first-name and last-name (one length each) and use DELIMITED BY SIZE for those. Then what's the point?

```
01  W-FULL-NAME.
    05  W-FIRST-NAME.
        10  FILLER OCCURS 0 TO 12 TIMES
            DEPENDING ON length-of-first-name.
            15  FILLER                        PIC X.
    05  SPACE-AFTER-FIRST-NAME                PIC X.
    05  W-MI-NAME.
        10  FILLER OCCURS 0 TO 2 TIMES
            DEPENDING ON length-for-mi.
            15  FILLER                        PIC X.
    05  W-LAST-NAME.
        10  FILLER OCCURS 0 TO 18 TIMES
            DEPENDING ON length-of-last-name.
            15  FILLER                        PIC X.
```

You have your two PERFORMs to get the length of the first-name and last-name (as already). You MOVE ZERO to length-for-mi if WS-MI-NAME is space, else make it two.

Then:

```
MOVE SPACE                  TO SPACE-AFTER-FIRST-NAME
MOVE FIRST-NAME             TO W-FIRST-NAME
MOVE LAST-NAME              TO W-LAST-NAME
MOVE MI-NAME                TO W-MI-NAME
```

The W-FULL-NAME, a variable-length field, contains the data you want in the format you want, and then you do what you like with it.

By shifting the "complexity" into the DATA DIVISION with the definition of the data, the code in the PROCEDURE DIVISION becomes very simple.

Try it out, and to see the formatted data, do this:

```
DISPLAY 
        ">"
        W-FULL-NAME
        "<"
```

The > and < are just to show you exactly what the data is (I always do that when DISPLAYing data). You'll see the length of the field changing with different test-data (assuming to test with different length data...).

Test with all the input as space, you'd see this on your SYSOUT spool dataset:

```
><
```

A zero-length field.

---

With reference-modification you'd do it something like this:

```
do your PERFORM to count the first-name  trailing spaces
MOVE FIRST-NAME             TO WS-FULL-NAME
ADD 1                       WS-SUB
  GIVING                    next-available-output

IF MI-NAME NOT EQUAL TO SPACE
    MOVE MI-NAME            TO WS-FULL-NAME 
                                ( next-available-output : 1 )
    ADD 2                   TO next-available-output
END-IF

do your PERFORM for the last-name
MOVE LAST-NAME              TO WS-FULL-NAME 
                                ( next-available-output : W-SUB )
```

The first MOVE to the output will copy the first name to the full-name. Neither needs to be reference-modified, the effect will be that other than the characters of the name the rest of the target field will be blank.

The number of characters present are known, so the next available position for data in the target field can be calculated by adding one.

The second MOVE is made conditional on whether there is any middle-initial data, and if so it is MOVEd to the next available output position calculated above. The number of bytes (one) MOVEd are limited in the target.

The third MOVE is like the second MOVE, except unconditional and the limit for the bytes MOVEd is variable.

Variations of the above are possible. There's a much neater way, but depends somewhat on your compiler. So which one are you using?

You calculation of the number of trailing blanks can be simplified:

```
  01  W-SUB                        COMP   PIC 9(4).

  PROCESS-LAST-NAME.
      MOVE ZERO                    TO W-SUB
      IF LAST-NAME NOT EQUAL TO SPACE
          MOVE FUNCTION LENGTH ( LAST-NAME )
                                   TO W-SUB
          PERFORM 
            UNTIL LAST-NAME ( W-SUB : 1 )
              NOT EQUAL TO SPACE
              SUBTRACT 1           FROM W-SUB
          END-PERFORM 
      END-IF
```

That way, you don't have to have the double termination-conditions. I'd REDEFINES the field, and use subscripting not reference-modification. I'd also rename W-SUB to indicate that it contains the length of the data.

Comment: Thanks BilI  - I was asked to do this with a STRING command but this looks good to me... Just started the job a few days ago. Haven't written in Cobol in 15 years. To be honest it's a regular mainframe, and I do not know which version of compiler as I haven't been allowed to compile anything as of yet ( :) ) and have been going through orientation. But I will find out Monday. Using IDMS wrapped around everything as well. Ed